# 1D array gets mapped to 2D plot and 3D array mapped to 2D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, pca

I am applying PCA and SVM to the `load_digits` dataset of Sci-Kit Learn.

Here is a piece of code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X_digits, y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
data = scale(X_digits)
reduced_data = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(data)

clf = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=1e6)
clf.fit(reduced_data, y_digits)
```

In the code above, `reduced_data` is a 2D numpy array,and y_digits is a 1D numpy array.

However,when i write the following code,i get a 2D plot for both lines:

```
plt.plot(y_digits,'o') 
plt.plot(reduced_data,y_digits,'o')
```

Shouldn't we get an error for the first line(as `y_digits` is 1D and matplotlib cannot draw 1D

plots), and a 3D plot for the second line as there are two input variables from `reduced_data` and one

`output` variable for `y_digits`? I am a bit confused as to how i should use matplotlib and interpret results

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I believe that the y_digits array is in the equivalent form of reshaping a 1D array with reshape(-1,1), thus I believe the matplotlib is interpreting a y out of the position of the value in the array. That is why when you call y_digits.shape the output is (1797,) the comma means the values are in a column.

If you want a 3D plot you should call it specifically like :

```
 #### Code for 3D Graph
 y = y_digits
 x = reduced_data[:,0] ### first column of 2D array
 z = reduced_data[:,1]  ### second column of 2D array

 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
 ax.scatter(x,y,z)
 plt.show()
```